# Switching visibility between select and text input with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to use the visible binding of knockout.js to switch between  and  depending on the value of the select. When the  value is = '5' I'd like to toggle the elements, can anyone explain where I am going wrong? I'm doing this within a foreach too, maybe I have the scope of the variables wrong for the comparison? Thanks

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" id="terms_table">
<thead>
<tr class="term_row">
<th><div align="center">Percentage</div></th>
<th><div align="center">Payment Terms</div></th>
<th><div align="center">Stage</div></th>
<th><div align="center">Delete</div></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: terms" >
<tr class='spec_row'>
<td class='center'><input size='5' data-bind="value : percentage" /></td>
<td class='center'>
<select data-bind='visible: $data.term != 5, options: $parent.termOptions, 
value: $data.term, optionsValue: "id", optionsText: "option"'></select>
<input data-bind='value: other, visible: $data.term == 5 ' />
</td>
<td class='center'><input size='60' data-bind="value : stage" /></td>
<td class='center' valign='middle'>
<input type='hidden' data-bind="value : id" />
<input type='hidden' data-bind="value : rank" />
<img width='12' height='12' class='move' src='/images/cursor_drag_arrow.png'  />
<img width='12' height='12' class='psuedo_link' src='/images/deleteCross.gif' 
data-bind='click: $parent.removeTerm' /></td>
</tr>  
</tbody>
</table>      
</div>
```

Comment: Is $data.term an observable property?

Comment: Yes, every property in the object is observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If term is an observable, you need to access it as such:

```
visible: $data.term() != 5
visible: $data.term() == 5
```